# Scala Spark filter rows in DataFrame with substring and character

Tags: regex, scala, apache-spark, dataframe, filter

I want to **filter** some rows in my `DF`, keeping rows where a column **starts with**  `"startSubString"` and do **not contain** the character `'#'`.

I can do what I want **with** **two filters**:

```
.filter( _!= col("theCol").contains("#"))
.filter( col("theCol").startsWith("startSubString"))
```

But was wondering if it could not be done in just one filter for better performance:

something like:

> .filter(col("theCol").rlike("^(startSubString).*^[^@]"))

although this **does not work**. What am I missing?

Comment: you can always use ||. `.filter( _!= col("theCol").contains("#") || col("theCol").startsWith("http"))` doesn't that work?

Comment: I would leave it as it is, I think its more readable than 1 huge logical expression. Spark's optimizer will combine the filter anyway, so I think you don't gain performance

Answer (score 2):

I use substr() all the time but I don't see why starsWith() wouldn't work either, but here is what I did...

```
.filter( (!(col("theCol").contains("#"))) && (col("theCol").substr(1,4) === ("http")))
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use **startsWith()**

```
.filter( !col("theCol").contains("#") && col("theCol").startsWith("startSubString") )
```